# Call ViewController from Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am a learner of i OS development. and i have a basic question.

I have `viewcontroller.h` and `ViewController.m`. and i have  `TableViewController.h` and `TableviewController.m` which  contains `viewDidload` method and all data source and delegate methods of tableviewcontroller.

How can i call `TableViewcontroller` class from `ViewController` and display Table in `ViewController.xib`

Comment: Why do you want to call TableViewController from ViewController? Can you be more specific? You can add TableViewController's view as a subview of ViewController, and add TableViewController as a child view controller of ViewController.

Comment: I have two table View with different specifications, i will call the particular table view as per my requirement.

Comment: What does 'call tableview' mean? You should be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Your specification is not clear, you are unable to convey the issue. But still for quick clue, if you need to use two tableviews in same controller then set its 'hidden' property to YES and NO according to needs while calling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load two differnt data into tableview means just create two array like `tabelArrayMain` & `tableArraySub`. Just relaod data with these array in same tableview instead of your separate class.

Comment: I have two table View with different specifications, i will call the particular table view as per my requirement. so i need to call tableview i want from view controller